# add custom field with where to query builder on laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I got stuck trying to add custom field on laravel query builder, this my database:

```
{
  id : 1
  name : aaa
  date : 201910 <--one month before
  val_min1 : null
  value_now : 4
},
{
  id : 2
  name : aaa
  date : 201911 <--month now
  val_min1 : null
  value_now : 2
},
{
  id : 3
  name : bbb
  date : 201911
  val_min1 : null
  value_now : 3
}
```

then i try to get data with

```
$pelanggan = Pemakaian::wheredate('201911')->get();
```

output :

```
{
  id : 2
  name : aaa
  date : 201911
  val_min1 : null
  value_now : 2
},
{
  id : 3
  name : bbb
  date : 201911
  val_min1 : null
  value_now : 3
}
```

expecting :

```
{
  id : 2
  name : aaa
  date : 201911
  val_min1 : 4 <--get from value_now where date one month before (201910)
  value_now : 2
},
{
  id : 3
  name : bbb
  date : 201911
  val_min1 : null
  value_now : 3
}
```

i try to merge the result from 2 query like this

```
$min1 = Pemakaian::select('value_now as val_min1')->wheredate('201910')->get();
$aaaa = $pelanggan->merge($min1);
```

but still failed, anyone can help me? thank you..

Answer (score 0):

Define which date field you want to retrieve

```
->whereDate('created', '=', date('Y-m-d'))
```

Comment: i just did select('value_now as val_min1')->wheredate('201910')->get();

Answer (score 0):

i got it.. i use triger on mysql

```
SET new.pemakaian_min1 = (Select pemakaian_kini from tbl_pemakaian
where tbl_pemakaian.periode = new.periode -1 AND tbl_pemakaian.nometer = new.nometer)
```

i hope this will help anyone with same problem
thank you..